# How to use JSON data as chartjs data?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, chart.js

In my controller I have an Action method that will find all questions in a table called Questions, and the answers for each question. This Action is of type ContentResult that will return a result serialized in Json format.

```
public ContentResult GetData()
        {
            foreach (var question in datalistQuestions)
            {
                 //queries
            } 
            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(questionlist), "application/json");    
        }
```

This is returning:

```
[{"countAgree":1,"countSomewhatAgree":0,"countDisagree":1},
{"countAgree":0,"countSomewhatAgree":1,"countDisagree":1},
{"countAgree":0,"countSomewhatAgree":1,"countDisagree":1}]
```

I want to display a chart for each question. The dynamic charts are created when im using hard coded dataset. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/f0rtunaMajor/d7v88w64/)
But how do I fetch this json data and use it as the dataset for my charts?

Answer (score 0):

Take your data as Objects. Consider Keys are Labels and Values in objects are Points. then draw the graph. using this code.

```
data = {"countAgree":1,"countSomewhatAgree":0,"countDisagree":1,
"countAgree":0,"countSomewhatAgree":1,"countDisagree":1,
"countAgree":0,"countSomewhatAgree":1,"countDisagree":1};

const CHART = document.getElementById('lineChart');

var lineChart = new Chart(CHART, {
type: 'line',
data: {
  labels: Object.keys(data),
  datasets: [{
     label: 'My first dataset',
     fill: false,
     lineTension: 0,
     backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
     borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
     borderCapStyle: 'butt',
     borderDash: [],
     borderDashOffset: 0.0,
     borderJointStyle: 'miter',
     data: Object.values(data)
  }]
  }
 })
```